# How to install latest OpenJdk on Ubuntu?

Tags: java, development, openjdk

I know that latest official openJDK is java version "1.7.0_25". But there is java version "1.7.0_40" in development. Does anyone know how to install openJDK "1.7.0_40" on an Ubuntu machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want openJDK 1.7.0_40 for 32-bit Ubuntu then do as

```
wget http://www.java.net/download/jdk7u40/archive/b40/binaries/jdk-7u40-fcs-bin-b40-linux-i586-16_aug_2013.tar.gz
```

If you want openJDK 1.7.0_40 for a 64-bit Ubuntu then do as

```
wget http://www.java.net/download/jdk7u40/archive/b40/binaries/jdk-7u40-fcs-bin-b40-linux-x64-16_aug_2013.tar.gz
```

Then make a directory.

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/jvm
```

Then move the downloaded tar to above created directory with

```
sudo mv jdk-7u40-fcs-bin-b40-linux-i586-16_aug_2013.tar.gz /usr/lib/jvm
```

similarly you can move 64-bit also if you want.

Then cd that directory

```
cd /usr/lib/jvm
```

Then untar the archive with

**32-Bit**

```
  sudo  tar -xvf jdk-7u40-fcs-bin-b40-linux-i586-16_aug_2013.tar.gz
```

**64-bit**

```
  sudo  tar -xvf jdk-7u40-fcs-bin-b40-linux-x64-16_aug_2013.tar.gz
```

Then paste these line one by one , and these are for intimating Ubuntu that this is your default java and path of it.

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_40/bin/javac" 1
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_40/bin/java" 1

sudo update-alternatives --set "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_40/bin/javac"
sudo update-alternatives --set "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_40/bin/java"
```

Then update your system profile , open it with

```
sudo gedit /etc/profile
```

then paste these lines

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_40
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export PATH
```

Now save & close.

Then reload your profile with

```
.  /etc/profile
```

Then we are done. check your java version.

Comment: Ya. I was able to find and download it. But how to install it?

Comment: @Braiam my dear brother ,I am little bit slow at typing. :P

Comment: Hahaha, so you are striving for being the fastest answerer in the west? ;)

Comment: @Braiam shhhhh!!! dont reveal the truths , its public :P :P